# Selenium opens chrome browser not the web page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to open a website in three browser using selenium grid. when i'm running my script,firefox and ie working fine.But chrome browser is opening with "data:," not with a URL.
Selenium Version 2.47
Chromedriver.exe 2.20
Chrome 46.0
Can any one tell me why?

```
@Parameters("browser")
   @BeforeTest
   public void launchapp(String browser) throws MalformedURLException
   {
      String URL = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium/selenium_grids.htm";
      if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
      {
         System.out.println(" Executing on FireFox");
         String Node = "http://10.101.7.220:5555/wd/hub";
         DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
         cap.setBrowserName("firefox");

         driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node), cap);

         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

         // Launch website
         driver.navigate().to(URL);
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
      }
      else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie"))
      {
         System.out.println(" Executing on IE");

         System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities
                .internetExplorer();

        capabilities
        .setCapability(
                InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
                true);

        capabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
         //driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node), capabilities);
        driver= new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

         // Launch website
         driver.navigate().to(URL);
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
      }
      else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) 
      {
           System.out.println("Running Chrome");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\mob150003576\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");

         driver = new ChromeDriver();
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Browser Type is Undefined");
      }
   }

   @Test
   public void sample()
   {
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()=' Home']")).click();

   }`
```

Comment: please share code which you have written to open website with chrome.

Comment: check if your chromedriver supports the browser version that you are trying now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chromedriver Not Loading Page in Selenium Tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776393/chromedriver-not-loading-page-in-selenium-tests)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice in your code is that you do not use RemoteWebDriver for running your IE or Chrome tests. The code can be simplified to read:

```
            String URL = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium/selenium_grids.htm";            
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "IEDriverServer.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities caps = null;

            switch(browser){
            case "chrome" : caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            break;
            case "firefox" : caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            break;
            case "ie" : caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
            caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
            break;
            } 

            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("grid string"), caps);
            driver.navigate().to(URL);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Please update the paths to browser driver as per your PC and add the specific capabilities you need.